Problems with cut and paste clipboard in a TEdit in an Android App with Delphi 11 CE
I am programming for Android with Delphi 11 CE.
In a TEdit component write a text, for example 'Hello friend' if you select all the text the clipboard menu appears, select cut and it works but if you select only one word, for example 'Hello' and I choose cut the application freezes. If I select a word from the 'Hello' text and choose to paste, there is no problem, but if I select all the TEdit text and choose to paste, the App freezes.
Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Why is this happening?
I have been testing on different phones and the same thing happens, sometimes it works but the app freezes shortly.
I did a test just putting TNumberBox, TEdit, TMemo and TButton objects, without adding any action and when selecting part of a number before the point, the application freezes.
    unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Memo.Types, FMX.ScrollBox,
  FMX.Memo, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.Edit, FMX.EditBox, FMX.NumberBox,
  FireDAC.Stan.Intf, FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove, FireDAC.Comp.BatchMove.Text, System.Actions,
  FMX.ActnList;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    NumberBox1: TNumberBox;
    Button1: TButton;

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

end.

Screenshot image

Delphi 12 CE was released a few weeks go. You should update to that version and see if the problem still occurs.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hello. Thank you very much for responding.
I'll install Delphi 12 CE to test.
I'll be happy to post the code.

I installed Delphi 12 CE and the application no longer freezes.But another problem arose:
I made a program that only contains two TEdit objects, in Edit1 I have the value 123.00, I select only 123 and copy or cut. In Edit2 I have written 0.00, I select only the zero before the dot and paste, the result is .12300 instead of 123.00
